# Dell U2414H Audio-Line out (HDMI cable)

Tags: 14.04, dell, pulseaudio, hdmi, speakers

I'm aware this isn't a strictly Ubuntu related question. Couldn't find an answer under Support for Dell U2414H. Googling it didn't help either.
Connected the speakers to Audio-Line out (via HDMI cable). All works fine, but as soon as the screen deems off, the speakers stop playing. I know there's a way to keep USB devices working with screen turned off (and it works), but it doen't seem to do the trick for speakers. Is there any way (apart from never dimming the sreen off, of course) to make speakers work (connected to monitor)? I'm Using Ununtu 14.04, Surely, I can connect the speakers to a PC soundcard, but that's not the question.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you should install [dell u2414h driver](http://www.serverdrivers.com/2017/04/dell-u2414h-driver-monitor.html) first and try reconnect you hdmi or audio cable

Answer (score 0):

> No. Once the monitor turns off, the HDMI or mDP/DP sending the audio
>   is ended. Using a screensaver rather than off or in powersave would be
>   an option. This way the HDMI or mDP/DP connection is still live.

I've got this answer from DELL Support forum. Makes sense.